# How can I enable the "no-daemon" functionality in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a problem with the Gradle daemon not showing println output from my plugin on subsequent runs.

I can workaround this problem by adding `--no-daemon` when I run from the command line.

When I run the Gradle task from IDEA though, when I add `--no-daemon` to the "script parameters" (not the "VM options"), the execution fails with:

```
10:59:32: Executing external task 'lambdaGet --no-daemon'...
Unknown command-line option '--no-daemon'.
```

How can I use the `--no-daemon` option with Gradle task configuration in IDEA?

**EDIT**:

Note that this question is specifically about how to do this in IDEA.  I don't want to disable the daemon globally, just from one specific IDEA run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `org.gradle.daemon=false` to your global `gradle.properties` file.

On Windows, you can create it in

`C:\Users\Username\.gradle\gradle.properties`

Answer (score 1):

did you try setting

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

in the **gradle.properties** in your **.gradle** directory

on my machine that folder is just under my home directory
so the file is at /Users/fred/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: I don't want to do that because it would disable all usage of the daemon, I only want to disable the daemon when I run this one specific task.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me to disable the daemon within a single IntelliJ run configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69106423/2434726

Comment: Doesn't work. This file is present and command line gradle listens to it, but IntelliJ still starts a daemon.