# Disabling Gradle daemon in a specific project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'd like to build certain projects without the use of of Gradle daemon. I've read that this can be done either by command-line argument `--no-daemon` or by changing Gradle properties under `.gradle/`. I need to disable it for just *some of the projects I build* under the root project though.

Is it possible via `settings.gradle`/`build.gradle` settings or am I better off making custom build script?

Comment: can this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192746/how-can-i-disable-a-task-in-build-gradle

Comment: @zipo13 I don't want to disable the build tasks, I just want to build the project without the daemon.. but maybe there is a setting for it and it could be applied like this, however I'm struggling to find the setting in the documentation..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply add `org.gradle.daemon=false` to a `gradle.properties` file in the project root folder.

The [daemon documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) mainly talks about disabling the daemon altogether on a machine but the [gradle properties documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) indicates that the location where a property / value pair is declared is irrelevant, they are sourced from different location, with overwrite rules.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try.. this is precisely what I was lloking for

Comment: Should this work for a specific submodule in a multi-project build? I tried it and it doesn't.